# How to rewrite HQL query with `distinct(year())` as Criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I ran below HQL Query, I got `[2015,2014]`

```
select DISTINCT(YEAR(SP.deliveryDate)) from SupplyPlan as SP where SP.samplePlan=2
```

Above query I need in criteria, I have tried like below but it is not working. Any suggestions?

```
def supplyPlanCriteria=SupplyPlan.createCriteria()
    def list=supplyPlanCriteria.list {
        projections {
        property("YEAR(deliveryDate)")
        }
        eq("samplePlan",samplePlan)
    }
```

Comment: If you have it working in HQL why not just use that?  You can inject parameters into an HQL query using either positional or named placeholders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Yes I can use that Roberts but I need criteria as I am using criteria overall in my project

Comment: "I'm using criteria queries because I'm using criteria queries" ?